# Is there an alternative to using resolve within an AngularJS config block to affirm my async data has arrived?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a curious issue regarding async data and resolve. I want to instantiate a service and use it to communicate w/my controllers in an AngularJS app. I'm able to do this w/o issue, but when I wait for my data to arrive using a routeProvider, I have to setup a variable. See below.

```
angularApp.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'stories.html',
                controller: 'StoryController as StoryCtrl',
                resolve: {
                    storiesPromise: function(storyDataAsFactory) {
                        return storyDataAsFactory.getStories;
                    }
                }

            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }
]);
```

I don't use storiesPromise and only insert it into my config block because it appears to be required. I tried removing it.

Is there a way to do the above w/o using the "storiesPromise" variable? As you see from my routeProvider I don't even really need to route as my entire app. is only one page. Yes, literally one page. How else can I ensure (using AngularJS) that my AJAX async. request has been fulfilled before instantiating my controller?

Comment: You can manually bootstrap your app when the data arrives but I doubt that's much better.